# when used /me/feed post, it seems that the facebook is using cached link url

Tags: facebook, api, caching, post

I have made an web site using facebook api. 
such as below

```js
var params = {
method : "stream.publish",
message : $("#textareaForSns").val(),
picture : urlForGameIcon,
name : titleForSns,
description : descriptionForSns, 
link : "http://hgurl.me/a5t" 
};

FB.api("/me/feed", "post", params ...
```

but, I found a problem. :(

I used link url as http://hgurl.me/a5t. this url is operating to redirect to another web site according to device type. (mobile or pc)

I changed redirection url later but it doesn't redirect to new url in each post. it occasionally redirect to old url yet

old one is 183.110.213.149:10080/ds/install.php.
new one is drgfriends.hangame.com

I don't know exactly how the facebook is working internally. I think that facebook is using cache data.

how can I make this short url working to redirect to new url I changed?

can I remove the cache?
please help me sir

thank you

Comment: Putting a URL through the [Debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhgurl.me%2Fa5t) usually fxes caching issues. (But you should take care of the error messages/warnings it gives as well.)